# eTags and multiple API endpoints

Tags: node.js, caching, etag

How do eTags work when I have multiple endpoints on my API?

```
/post/:id
/user/:id
```

Does each request to the API have it's own eTag associated to the endpoint url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/6a68/4971859

This answers that.

An ETag, or entity tag, is an opaque token that identifies a version of the component served by a particular URL.